# Start new activities / screens on multiple devices

Tags: android, screen

I need to develop an Android app which creates a number of screens. Each screen will run on different devices simultaneously.  I am using eclipse and wrote 3 screens by starting new activities, but have no idea how to make new screens start on different devices.  Any Suggestions?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by screens?

Comment: check the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: check this out may be it might be helpful for you http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Comment: It means that I have an app which has a number of screen interfaces which perform different functions at the same time, but each screen will work on different devices.

Comment: I know there are a lot of articles talking about designing for multiple screen sizes or resolution, but they are not exactly what I want.